# Empty result file using scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

just started learning python so sorry if this is a stupid question!

I'm trying to scrape real estate data from this website: https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?pn=2&r=10 using scrapy.

Ideally, in the end I'd get a file containing all available real estate offers and their respective address, price, area in m2, and other details (e.g. connection to public transport).

I built a test spider with scrapy but it always returns an empty file. I tried a whole bunch of different xpaths but can't get it to work. Can anyone help? Here's my code:

```
import scrapy

class GetdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'getdata' 
  allowed_domains = ['immoscout24.ch']
  start_urls = ['https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10',
  'https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?pn=2&r=10',
  'https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?pn=3&r=10',
  'https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?pn=4&r=10',
  'https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?pn=5&r=10']

  def parse(self, response):

    single_offer = response.xpath('//*[@class="Body-jQnOud bjiWLb"]')


    for offer in single_offer: 
        offer_price = offer.xpath('.//*[@class="Box-cYFBPY jPbvXR Heading-daBLVV dOtgYu xh-   highlight"]/text()').extract()
        offer_address = offer.xpath('.//*[@class="Address__AddressStyled-lnefMi fUIggX"]/text()').extract_first()

        yield {'Price': offer_price,
                'Address': offer_address}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all of , You need to add your real user agent . I injected user-agent in settings.py file. I also have corrected the xpath selection and made pagination in start_urls which type of next page pagination is 2 time fister than other types.This is the woeking example.

```
import scrapy
class GetdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'getdata'
    allowed_domains = ['immoscout24.ch']
    start_urls = ['https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?pn='+ str(x)+'&r=10' for x in range(1,5)]
                

    def parse(self, response):

        single_offer = response.xpath('//*[@class="Content-kCEgNG degSLr"]')

        for offer in single_offer:
            name = offer.xpath('.//*[@class="Box-cYFBPY jPbvXR Heading-daBLVV dOtgYu"]/span/text()').extract_first()
            offer_address = offer.xpath('.//*[@class="AddressLine__TextStyled-eaUAMD iBNjyG"]/text()').extract_first()

            yield {'title': name,
                   'Address': offer_address}
```

**Output:**

```
{'title': 'CHF 950.—', 'Address': 'Friedackerstrasse 6, 8050 Zürich, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 220.—', 'Address': 'Freilagerstrasse 40, 8047 Zürich, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 220.—', 'Address': 'Freilagerstrasse 40, 8047 Zürich, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 220.—', 'Address': 'Freilagerstrasse 40, 8047 Zürich, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 4020.—', 'Address': 'Uitikonerstrasse 9, 8952 Schlieren, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 260.—', 'Address': 'Buckhauserstrasse 45/49, 8048 Zürich, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 260.—', 'Address': 'Letzigraben 75, 8003 Zürich, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 2655.—', 'Address': 'Weiningerstr. 53, 8103 Unterengstringen, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 320.—', 'Address': 'Baslerstrasse 60, 8048 Zürich, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 190.—', 'Address': 'Neugutstrasse 66, 8600 Dübendorf, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 180.—', 'Address': 'Herostrasse 9, 8048 Zürich, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
{'title': 'CHF 180.—', 'Address': 'Herostrasse 9, 8048 Zürich, ZH'}
2022-03-22 00:58:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.immoscout24.ch/de/buero-gewerbe-industrie/mieten/ort-zuerich?r=10>
```

... so on